# How to generate a unique class (loop) for each div (php)?

Tags: php, html, css, unique

I'm struggling to find/integrate any solutions I've found online to help generate a unique class for each div. It would be fine if for example, the div was called "gallery-div" and 1 was added on to each div eg gallery-div1, gallery-div2, gallery-div3 etc.

This is what I currently have (doesn't have a unique class set up yet):

```css
.headstone-category-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
} /* Sets headstone category divs to take up 100% of the available width within its container */

.grid-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
} /* Sets the way the headstone category divs are displayed (horizontally) 
and allows for them to wrap round each other when screen adjusting */

.grid-item2 {
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} /* Sets padding between headstone category divs, sets sizing and sets for row to be 5 divs */

.grid-item3 {
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} /* Sets padding between headstone category divs, sets sizing and sets for row to be 5 divs */

.wrapping-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  color: currentColor;
} /* Allows the user to be able to click anywhere within the headstone category div to access the href link */

.grid-item-wrapper {
  padding: 4px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
  -moz-box-sizing: initial;
  box-sizing: initial;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(223, 219, 219) , rgb(252, 252, 250));
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), margin 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), box-shadow 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1);
  transition: padding 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), margin 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), box-shadow 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
} /* Adds styling, sets sizing and sets transition speed of the headstone category div */

.grid-item-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgb(223, 219, 219),
    rgb(252, 252, 250)
  );
  cursor: pointer;
} /* Allows content to use full width and height of the headstone category div. Also styles the div. */

.grid-item-container2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
} /* Allows content to use full width and height of the headstone category div. Also styles the div. */

.grid-image-top2 {
  min-height: 375px;
  max-height: 575px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 5%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  cursor: pointer;
} /* Sets sizing and positioning of the images within the headstone category divs. 
This also removes the white background of each image (mix-blend-mode: multiply;) */ 

.grid-image-top2.lawn-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/heartmemorials/images/heart2.jpg");
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the lawn memorials */

.grid-image-top2.lawn-memorials2 {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/heartmemorials/images/heart2.jpg");
} /* I WANT TO BE ABLE TO DISPLAY THE DIFFERENT IMAGES LIKE THIS */

.grid-image-top2.lawn-memorials3 {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/heartmemorials/images/heart2.jpg");
} /* I WANT TO BE ABLE TO DISPLAY THE DIFFERENT IMAGES LIKE THIS */

.headstone-desc-box {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(223, 219, 219) , rgb(252, 252, 250));
}

.grid-item3:hover .grid-item-wrapper {
  padding: 1.5% 1.5%;
  margin: -1.5% -1.5%;
  background-color: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(223, 219, 219) , rgb(252, 252, 250));
} /* Adds the padding for when users hover over the headstone category div. 
Also adds gradient to the small extra space added within the padding */

.grid-item-content {
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
} /* Adds padding to the text within the headstone category divs */
```

```html
<!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid                       transform: scaleX(-1);-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="grid-row"> <!-- Start of div -->

<div class="grid-item3 show"> <!-- Start of div -->
    <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->      
        <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-item-container2 column lawn"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <div class="grid-image-top2 lawn-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
                    
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
        <div class="headstone-desc-box">
        <p><strong>TXC10 (LM)</strong><br><br>A gracefully sculpted Angel with prominent polished granite wings shown in Lavender Blue and Blue Pearl.</p>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End of div -->
</div> <!-- End of div -->

<div class="grid-item3 show"> <!-- Start of div -->
    <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->      
        <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-item-container2 column lawn"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <div class="grid-image-top2 lawn-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
                    
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
        <div class="headstone-desc-box">
        <p><strong>TXC10 (LM)</strong><br><br>A gracefully sculpted Angel with prominent polished granite wings shown in Lavender Blue and Blue Pearl.</p>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End of div -->
</div> <!-- End of div -->

<div class="grid-item3 show"> <!-- Start of div -->
    <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->      
        <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-item-container2 column lawn"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <div class="grid-image-top2 lawn-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
                    
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
        <div class="headstone-desc-box">
        <p><strong>TXC10 (LM)</strong><br><br>A gracefully sculpted Angel with prominent polished granite wings shown in Lavender Blue and Blue Pearl.</p>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End of div -->
</div> <!-- End of div -->

</div> <!-- End of grid-row div-->
</div> <!-- End of row div -->
```

The reason I don't just change the current div classes is due to me having the divs in a separate file which gets re-used over and over again like the following:

```
<?php
    include 'grid-items/top-lawn.php';
?> <!-- This sets alls the divs for the grid items -->
  <p><strong>TXC10 (LM)</strong><br><br>A gracefully sculpted Angel with prominent polished granite wings shown in Lavender Blue and Blue Pearl.</p>
<?php
    include 'grid-items/bottom-lawn.php';
?> <!-- This sets alls the divs for the grid items -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if I understand right ...

As I understand you could do:

1. advise same class 'grid-item` to all divd you want to style the same way
2. note the class with the style in your css

```
// css 
// has been .grid-item1|2|3|4 before
.grid-item {
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

// html
// use the above class instead of .grid-item1|2|3|4...
<div class="grid-item show"> <!-- Start of div -->
    <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->      
        <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-item-container2 column lawn"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <div class="grid-image-top2 lawn-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
                    
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
        <div class="headstone-desc-box">
        <p><strong>TXC10 (LM)</strong><br><br>A gracefully sculpted Angel with prominent polished granite wings shown in Lavender Blue and Blue Pearl.</p>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End of div -->
</div> <!-- End of div -->


// .... ADD OTHER GRID ITEMS AS WELL ....
```